# WordPress Customizer JavaScript Hide Background Image

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a checkbox control in my WordPress Customizer to display a banner image if checked and hide it if unchecked but the javascript isn't working:

```
wp.customize( 'display_banner_image', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        if ( false === to ) {
            $( '#banner' ).css('background-image', 'none' );
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized what I'm trying to do is redundant. The WordPress Customizer has built in buttons for Select Image, Remove Image and Default Image.

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to tell, since you're not able to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your error, but I know you can't reproduce this in any snippet environment.

However, your posted code seems out of context.

My first guess is the problem is around the `if ( false === to )` condition.

1. Do you have a previously declared variable named `to`?
2. If (1.), you should `console.log(newval)` and see what it contains. Else, I'm wild-guessing `to` should be replaced with `newval`? This is completely out of context.
3. Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors in console but I just realized you're right, `to` was supposed to be `newval` (although it also works when both are `to` also). It now removes the image when unchecked but now when it's checked again, it doesn't put the image back (i.e. `background-image` remains `none`). @andrei-gheorghiu

Comment: There is no easy way for anyone to help you. I know you cannot reproduce the WP `Customizer` in any snippet, because of it being a preview tool. The console log is your best friend. Use it every step of the way, see what is inside every variable you are working with and use that to get to next step until it works the way you want. Good luck!